# How do I get a class function to increment integer variable to be used as a dictionary key

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, key, increment

I have a class that creates a Customer Object, which will be stored in a Dictionary. The Dictionary uses a (Of TInteger, Customer). 
When a new customer is added It needs to have a unique ID that a user can use to search for a customer. I plan on using the Dictionary Key as the ID.

When my addCustomer form click the addCustomer button. It creates the customer object. Then puts that object into the dictionary value. The key is set by calling a function in the Customer class which creates and sets a static variable. Then adds 1 and returns.

---

Here is my Customers Class ( minus code that is not needed for help )

```
Public Class Customers
'Create a dictionary to hold the new customer
Friend customerDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Customers)

Private cFirstName As String 'first name
Private cLastName As String 'last name
Private cAddress As String 'field to address
Private cContactInfo As String 'contact information i.e. a telephone number Or an e-mail address
Private cCountry As Boolean 'country the customer lives In
Friend cMortgage As List(Of Mortgage) 'customer has one or more mortgages

Public Sub New(cFirstName1 As String, cLastName1 As String, cAddress1 As String, cContactInfo1 As String, cCountry1 As Boolean)
    Me.CFirstName1 = cFirstName1
    Me.CLastName1 = cLastName1
    Me.CAddress1 = cAddress1
    Me.CContactInfo1 = cContactInfo1
    Me.CCountry1 = cCountry1
    cMortgage = addCMortgage()
End Sub
......
Code for getters and setters
......

'Function to create a new customer ID/Key
Public Function getCustomerID() As Integer
    'Create variable that adds 1 everytime a customer is created. Then use that as customer Id and as the Customer Dictionary Key.
    Static cIdKey As Integer = 0
    cIdKey += 1
    Return cIdKey
End Function
End Class
```

---

Here is my code for my addCustomerForm which creates the object and calls the function and sets the dictionary.

```
Public Class frmAddNewCustomer

Private Sub frmAddNewCustomer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub btnAddMortgage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMortgage.Click
    Dim cCountry As Boolean
    Dim cAddress As String  

    ......'Set up address format and code validation.....

    'Create the Customer object
    Dim Customers As New Customers(txtfName.ToString, txtLName.ToString, cAddress, txtContact.ToString, cCountry)

    'Create a customers Dictionary to store the Customer.
    Customers.customerDict.Add(Customers.getCustomerID, Customers)

    'Close the add customer form
    Me.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Shouldnt the `Id` be something less abstract, like the actual CustomerID from whereever it is stored?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be better, but this also makes less data saved in the customer object?

Comment: No, an int Id is going to "cost" the same as an int you create and increment.

Comment: Good point, I'm a new student and probably have a small brain. Could you tell me what would be better about not using the key as the ID. I assume the other option would be to store the ID in the Customer object and find Customers by searching the Customer object that would be stored in the dictionary.

Comment: A unique ID (not just a counter) makes sense of the code will be fishing them back that way.  If *users* are going to be requesting to view/edit customers, mush less so.  In the real world, they are never going to ask to see #4 - they want to see the one named "Betty's Cupcakes".  At that point it might as well be a list and use linq to search it.  If it is db data, leave it in a datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In the Customer Class I changed the declaration of the dictionary to public shared. Also, instead of using Static for the variable to increment. I made it Private Shared and moved it out of the function and to the class declaration area

```
Public Class Customers

    'Create a dictionary to hold the new customer
    Public Shared customerDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Customers)

    Private Shared cIdKey As Integer = 0
```

Comment: You can and indeed are encouraged to tick your own answers - It helps other users searching for an answer see that this answer works.